# Remove the last special characters of strings in a list

Tags: python, string, replace

I have an array with words, some ending with special characters. I would like all the special characters at the end of the words to be deleted. Is there an elegant way to do it?

```
aArray=["palabra...","algo,.", "si ...", "onomatopeña", "asi;","www.google.com"]
```

output:

```
aArray=["palabra","algo", "si", "onomatopeña", "asi","www.google.com"]
```

I was trying this:

```
rxx = re.compile(r'(.*)([.,]{2,})')  # Extend [.,] as needed; {2,} means >= 2
aArray=["encontarla....", "esta,.", "sr.", "texto", 'www.google.com', 'encontrarla.']
aArray=([rxx.sub(lambda m: m.group(1), word) for word in a])
```

I think I did not understand at all. For example the string `www.google.com` as it is a url, should not elminate the dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to do that. Although your question is not very clear on the definition of 'special characters', but here is a sample code that gives the output that you posted:

```
import re

aArray=["palabra...","algo,.", "si ...", "onomatopeña", "asi;", "www.google.com"]

for i in range(len(aArray)):
    aArray[i] = re.sub(r'[.,;]+$', '', aArray[i]).strip()
```

**Output:**

```
['palabra', 'algo', 'si', 'onomatopeña', 'asi', 'www.google.com']
```

If by 'special character' you mean any non-alphanumeric, then you can use this:

```
import re

aArray=["palabra...","algo,.", "si ...", "onomatopeña", "asi;", "www.google.com"]

for i in range(len(aArray)):
    aArray[i] = re.sub(r'[^\w]+$', '', aArray[i]).strip()
```

**Output:**

```
['palabra', 'algo', 'si', 'onomatopeña', 'asi', 'www.google.com']
```

Also note the `strip()`, it is there to remove the trailing spaces

**UPDATE**

The `$` at the end of regular expressions, means that we expect this pattern to be at the end and nothing else should be after it. So it can handle your URLs as well.

Comment: I think I did not understand at all. For example the word www.google.com as it is a web page, should not elminate the points. I update the question

Comment: Are the strings totally random? or are they all urls?
Because if they are of different patterns, it is very hard to find a regular expression that fits exactly to your case

Comment: basically as the title of the question says, remove special characters from the end. A web page are valid characters.

Answer (score 2):

To strip all non-word characters only from the end of the strings:

```
import re

aArray = ["palabra...", "algo,.", "si ...", "onomatopeña", "asi;", "www.google.com"]

aArray = [re.sub(r'\W+$', '', s) for s in aArray]
```

Result:

```
['palabra', 'algo', 'si', 'onomatopeña', 'asi', 'www.google.com']
```

Explanation:

`\W+` matches any number of non-word characters, and `$` anchors the match to the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using a list comprehension and `filter`, without needing to use regex:

```
>>> aArray=["palabra...","algo,.", "si ...", "onomatopeña", "asi;","www.google.com"]
>>> [s.rstrip('.;, ') for s in aArray]
['palabra', 'algo', 'si', 'onomatopeña', 'asi', 'www.google.com']
```

Note I'm assuming `'.;, '` are the all "special characters you're referring to.

Comment: thanks genious, I think I did not understand at all. For example the word www.google.com as it is a web page, should not elminate the points. I update the question

Comment: @unusuario Please try avoid editing your question and changing conditions in the future, after users have offered answers. Such an action invalidates current answers. Anyway, I edited my answer to address your new conditions.

Comment: Sorry, I did not do it with bad intentions. I think I did not make myself understood. I assure you that it was not my intention to adjust the question for my convenience. I put the example of the website to make me understand better. excuse me

Comment: Its fine @unusuario. I'm not at all angry. I understand that questions can change. I was simply advising you in the future to take more time to formulate the conditions of your question so that you don't have to edit your question and potentially invalidate current answers.

Comment: thanks, it seems to work. but I do not understand well what you did. Do you do a digit verification? If so, why do not the points on www.google.com get deleted? thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Essentially @unusuario, I'm telling Python to only remove special charters from the end of the very end of the string. That's what [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20rstrip#str.rstrip) is doing.